# How to Re-write function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I had seen this question on an interview a few months ago, but I wanted to confirm my answer.

(I'm writing a blog post of past interview questions to clarify my answers.)

```
if (foo) { bar.doSomething(el); }
else { bar.doSomethingElse(el); }
```

Answer:

```
foo ? bar.doSomething(el) : bar.doSomethingElse(el);
```

Comment: What is the question to which you've provided the tentative answer?

Comment: looks right to me, although I wouldn't typically use it for readability.

Comment: lol.  I've never seen an if statement interpreted as a question???  Were you playing Jeopardy?

Comment: This is called shorthand, not rewrite function. rewrite function means something completely different like overwriting the original declaration of a function

Comment: How is this not a `real question`?

Answer (score 2):

You could also write it this way (slightly less readable):

```
(foo ? bar.doSomething : bar.doSomethingElse)(el);
```

Or even the pathological, though shorter:

```
bar[foo ? 'doSomething' : 'doSomethingElse'](el);
```

which can be further condensed (in your example case) to:

```
bar['doSomething' + (foo ? '' : 'Else')](el);
```

And if you really want to get rid of the conditional you can do something sneaky like:

```
bar[['doSomething', 'doSomethingElse'][+!!foo]](el);
```